# How to retry a Spring WebSocketGraphQlClient query

Tags: java, spring, websocket, graphql, spring-graphql

Using Spring Boot 3.2.4 with Spring WebFlux/GraphQL subscription via Websocket.

Server A exposes a graphqlSubscription, and Server B consumes the subscription.
They both use the same components (reactor/netty).

Steps to Reproduce:

```java
// Client side, Initialize the webSocketGraphQlClient
ReactorNettyWebSocketClient reactorNettyWebSocketClient = new ReactorNettyWebSocketClient(HttpClient.create(), build);
WebSocketGraphQlClient.builder(serverUrl, reactorNettyWebSocketClient).build();
    
// Call sample
webSocketGraphQlClient
 .document(query)
 .retrieveSubscription(path)
 .toEntity(XXXX.class)
 .retryWhen(Retry.fixedDelay(5, Duration.ofMinutes(1))).blockLast()
```

**Not Working Cases**

Case 1:

- Run the client, do not start the server
- Wait for the 1st RETRY.
- `GraphQlTransportException => connection refused.`
- Run the server.
- Nexts retries will fail with the same reason.

Case 2:

- Run the server.
- Run the client.
- Communication between both is working fine
- Kill the server.
- Wait for the FIRST RETRY
- `WebSocketDisconnectedException -> connection is closed or lost.`
- Wait for the SECOND RETRY.
- `GraphQlTransportException => connection refused.`
- Rerun the server.
- Nexts retries will fail with the same reason.

**Working Case**

- Run the server.
- Run the client.
- Communication between both is working fine
- Kill the server.
- Wait for the FIRST RETRY
- `WebSocketDisconnectedException -> connection is closed or lost.`
- Rerun the server.
- OK, the retry is working.

Is there a way to resume a WebSocket connection when the client failed to connect to the remote server?

Link to the github question : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-graphql/issues/826